# Removing ForeFront Client Security and MOM Server - How to repoint managed clients to unmanaged?

Tags: microsoft-forefront, mom

Like the title says, how can I remove FCS and MOM and not have the clients wait for updates from the server and go on its own to get updates from Windows Update automatically? Reason for this is we don't really need the FCS and MOM server and they're just taking up a lot of resources on our VM box.

All the information I've seen online are about how to get unmanaged clients to be managed by FCS and MOM. I'm trying to do the opposite here. I have a lab I can test this with so no problem with getting it wrong the first time but I'd rather save time, really.

I understand that this may be counter productive, but all this automation makes me lazy and not check any of the workstations for some light maintenance because I know something's behind me to take care of it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to MOM administrator console and select Agent Managed computers
2. Select the computer on the right-hand side and click "Force to unmanaged Management node" and click Yes.
3. (optional based on whatever you're doing) Go to Agentless Managed computers and right-click the computer and select Delete.

Depending on how you want to manage updates from there, leave it and WSUS will handle pushing updates to it.  Or configure your GPO that handles Windows Updates and remove the setting that points to an intranet location.

That should be it.

Comment: Thanks! I've already done the WSUS intranet location beforehand but entirely forgot about the MOM setting.